# Build a differential equation with solutions equal quotient of two solutions of another differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

For a differential equation with meromorphic coefficients of the form 
$$y’’+ p(z) y’ + q(z) y = 0$$
How to build a differential equation with all solutions satisfying the form $y1/y2$, where $y1, y2$ are any two nonzero solutions of the original equation?

Edit

By using Gribouillis's hint, we can get $f''y_2+2y_2'f'+pf'y_2=0$, what can I do on next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Write $y_1(z) = f(z) y_2(z)$ and compute $y_1'' + p(z)y_1' + q(z)y_1$

The result is an relation involving $f''$ and $f'$. This relation can be seen as a first order homogeneous equation in $f'$. It can be solved to get $f'(z)$, hence $f(z)$, hence $y_1$ in terms of $y_2$ and two arbitrary constants.